# Selecting only polygons with certain variable in them using ArcMap?

Tags: arcmap, polygon, select-by-location

I have green space polygons for London and also illegal pollution areas in polygons in ArcMap. How would I go about selecting only the green space polygons that have pollution areas in them (so the green spaces with no pollution in are not selected). I know this could be done by individually selecting by attributes but I have around 1,400 green spaces to consider so this would take a long time.

Does anyone know what tool/s I’d need to use to select just these green space polygons?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Have you investigated Select By Location?

Comment: Yeah I tried select by location but it just selects the areas of pollution inside the green spaces. It is the green spaces with the pollution that I want to select

Comment: Can you give us more sense of your data? Perhaps show part of the attribute table?

Comment: If you get the inverse of what you want from SelectByLocation, you should try reversing the operands.